# View validations using ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, validation, tableview, reactive-cocoa

I have a tableview with custom cell containing 4 textfields and a button UPDATE. I show the data coming from web service in tableview. When the any  one of the textfields is empty, UPDATE button should be hidden.

MODEL has the following properties to be mapped with the 4 textfields in each cell

```
@interface ClaimRequestModel : JSONModel 

@property (strong, atomic) NSString <Optional> *id;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString <Optional> *trip_id;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString <Optional> *item;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString <Optional> *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString <Optional> *description;
@end
```

I have tried to create RACSignal on property "name" in the TableViewController as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [savedClaims enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(ClaimRequestModel *claim, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            [claimSignals addObject:RACObserve(claim, name)];
    }];
     enableCostSignal = [RACSignal combineLatest:costSignals];
    [self setupClaimTypeSignal:[RACSignal combineLatest:claimSignals]];
//        [self.tableView reloadData];

}
-(void)setupClaimTypeSignal:(RACSignal*) signal {
    [[signal map:^id(RACTuple *values) {
        for (NSString *string in values) {
            if ([string isEmpty]) {
                return @(NO);
            }
        }
        return @(YES);
    }] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        self.validInput = [x boolValue];
    }];

}
```

It works fine with one property "name" and I would like to observe all the properties in the ClaimRequestModel.

Do I need to create multiple signal arrays for each property? if so, what if the model has more than 15 properties?

Could any one please help me in the best practice using ReactiveCocoa?

Comment: "savedClaims" is array of objects r8?

Comment: Can you please check my answer and give response that its working or not?

Comment: I have already upvoted you, Thanks a lot @EktaMakadiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to add signal in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to check the condition.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   ClaimRequestCell *cell = [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ClaimRequestCell" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] firstObject];

   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cell.reuseIdentifier];

   ClaimRequestModel *claim = [savedClaims objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   RACSignal *valid = [RACSignal
                    combineLatest:@[[RACObserve(claim, name) ignore:nil], [RACObserve(claim, item) ignore:nil],[RACObserve(claim, trip_id) ignore:nil] ]
                    reduce:^(NSString *name, NSString *item, NSString *trip_id ) {
                        return @([name length] == 0 && [item length] == 0 && [trip_id length] == 0);
                    }];

   RAC(cell.updateButton, enabled) = valid;

   return cell;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Ekta it is working. As the model can be deleted from savedClaims, how can we unbind the deleted models as cellFroRowAtIndexPath will not be executed for such models?

Comment: @satyanarayana I am not getting you. You want to remove the deleted items from tableview r8?

Comment: Suppose that savedClaims has 2 models so we see 2 cells, fine with this. Later, if the 2 cell.name is empty then  model.name will be empty so that updateButton will not be enabled. Now, if I remove 2 cell then model will be removed from savedClaims but the 1 cell has valid data but udpateButton is not getting enabled instead of getting enabled. So, is there any way to get unbind any object in RAC?

Comment: @satyanarayana For that you need to observe your array and if your array of object is replace or remove then you need to reload your table view.

Comment: Thanks @Ekta, [tableview reloadData] worked , instead of  [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];, we miss tableview animation here. No problem, it works great. How about the performance if we keep on adding these RACSignal each time?

Comment: @satyanarayana Its my pleasure to help you. Kindly accept and upvote my answer. This will give me motivation :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120665/discussion-between-satyanarayana-and-ekta-makadiya).

Comment: Thanks @Ekta, it helps me.  How about the performance with too many signals?